# How can I enable outgoing HTTP/HTTPS requests on an EC2 in a public subnet within a VPC on Amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, https, subnet, amazon-vpc

I set up a VPC using scenario 2 from the AWS Docs:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario2.html

I've assigned an Elastic IP to an EC2 instance running in a Public Subnet. SSH works fine and I can access the website running on it. I cannot, however make outgoing HTTP or HTTPS requests ( I noticed this when trying to run `yum update` ).

I believe all my security settings are correct. Am I not able to make outgoing HTTP/HTTPS requests through the internet gateway? I specifically requested not to have a public IP assigned to this instance when created, because I knew I was going to assign an Elastic IP that gets liked to the website DNS. I have a NAT setup for instances in the Private Subnet, but I currently only have RDS instances running there, so I have not tested outgoing requests from there.

The security group for that EC2 instance has the following outbound rules:
[image]

The routes table for that subnet has the following settings:
[image]

The Network ACL has the following settings:
[image]

The default DHCP Option Set has the following settings:

```
domain-name = ec2.internal
domain-name-servers = AmazonProvidedDNS
```

The default `/etc/resolv.conf` settings are:

```
search ec2.internal
nameserver 10.0.0.2
```

The CIDR Blocks for the VPC and Subnets are as follows:

```
VPC: 10.0.0.0/16
Public Subnet: 10.0.0.0/24
Private DB Subnet in US East 1A: 10.0.1.0/24
Private DB Subnet in US East 1C: 10.0.2.0/24
```

Comment: Does `curl http://www.google.com/` fail?

Comment: Yes. I cannot access any sites, curl, wget, ping, etc. -- `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: www.google.com`

Comment: Nameserver issue, perhaps?

Comment: Interesting ... that does seem to be the problem. I can ping IP Addresses for Google.com. What does this mean for my VPC? What is the problem?

Comment: Check your /etc/resolv.conf and your AWS Console for DHCP Option Sets.

Comment: The DHCP Options are `domain-name = ec2.internal` AND `domain-name-servers = AmazonProvidedDNS`. The settings in `/etc/resolve.conf` match ( except it's `10.0.0.2` instead of `AmazonProvidedDNS` ) ... Should I change this to use a public DNS server like Google's: 8.8.8.8? Why won't Amazon's DNS resolve anything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**STILL WONDERING**

Why doesn't the provided AWS DNS Server work in this case?

**PROBLEM**

The problem was that DNS names weren't resolving via the [local DNS server than Amazon provided when originally creating the VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_DHCP_Options.html#DHCPOptions). I discovered that I could make outgoing HTTP/HTTPS connections to IP addresses, which didn't need to contact a DNS server to resolve.

**SOLUTION**

I had to create a custom DHCP Option Set within the Amazon VPC AWS Console and set Google's public DNS IPs as `domain-name-servers = 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4`.

Then I had to update `/etc/resolv.conf` setting the same thing:

`nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4`

Comment: Like a comment above said, what are your DHCP option sets and the default /etc/resolv.conf settings?  Also what are the vpc and subnet cidr blocks?

Comment: I added those details to the bottom of the question.

Comment: After making those changes, did you have to restart something? I've added a DHCP option set, and also changed the lines in resolv.conf, but the `curl http://google.com` still doesn't work.